# Form validation not working with Blazor server

Tags: c#, validation, blazor, blazor-server-side

Form code

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebLab.Pages._9;

public class Form
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Name too long")]
    public string Name;

    [Required]
    [MinLength(2)]
    public string City;
    public string Address;
    public string Birthday;
    public string Mail;
}
```

Page code

```
@page "/9/2"
@inject IConfiguration config;
@using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

<EditForm Model="@form">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator/>
    <ValidationSummary></ValidationSummary>
    <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="@form.Name" class="form-control"></InputText>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>City</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="@form.City" class="form-control"></InputText>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Address</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="@form.Address" class="form-control"></InputText>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Birthdate</label>
        <InputDate @bind-Value="@form.Birthday" class="form-control"></InputDate>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>E-mail</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="@form.Mail" class="form-control"></InputText>
    </div>

    <br />
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send" />
</EditForm>

@code
{
    private Form form = new();

    private string connString;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        connString = config.GetConnectionString("default");
    }
}
```

The code compiles, however the validation seems to not work properly, i.e. no error messages or something. If I add OnValidSubmit event to the form, it is raised on button click. I have no idea where is the problem, tried to follow this guide: https://blazor-university.com/forms/validation/

Answer (score 1):

The problem was actually in form code. All fields should instead be properties with `get/set`